# Finding Outliers and ChiSquare Matrix of a purely Categorical Dataset

Tags: r, data-analysis, outliers, chi-squared

I have been assigned the task of making a prediction model. The data set given to me is purely categorical and consists of 92 variables. A portion of it is given below:

```
   Dataset <- structure(list(Age.Group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
   4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
   4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
  "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 
   2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
   2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
   2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
   1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), LOS = structure(c(2L, 
   2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
   1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
   2L), .Label = c("Abnormal", "Normal"), class = "factor"), Day.to.Operation = structure(c(1L, 
   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
   1L), .Label = c("Abnormal", "Normal"), class = "factor"), Admit.Source = structure(c(2L, 
   2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
   1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
   2L), .Label = c("Emergency", "Outpatient clinic"), class = "factor"), 
  Insurance.Payors = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
   3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
   1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Basic medical insurance for urban residents", 
"Basic medical insurance for urban residents Others", "Free Medical Care", 
"New Rural Cooperative Medical Care", "Self payment"), class = "factor"), 
Current.Recent.Smoker...1.year. = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Hypertension = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
Dyslipidemia = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), Family.History.of.Premature.CAD = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
MI.History = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), Heart.Failure.History = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
PCI.History = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), BMI.Group = structure(c(3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
Cerebrovascular.Disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Peripheral.Arterial.Disease = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
Chronic.Lung.Disease = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor"), Diabetes.Mellitus = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
Diabetes.Therapy = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Diet", 
"Insulin", "N/A", "Oral"), class = "factor"), Heart.Rate = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Abnormal", "Normal"), class = "factor"), 
CAD.Presentation = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non STEMI  7 days", 
"Silent myocardial ischemia  14 days", "Stable angina  42 days", 
"STEMI  7 days", "Unstable angina  60 days"), class = "factor"), 
STEMI.Non.STEMI.Onset.Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "17"), class = "factor"), STEMI.Non.STEMI.Estimated.Time = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
Anginal.Classification.w.in.2.Weeks = structure(c(2L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("CCS I", "CCS II", "CCS III", "CCS IV", 
"No symptoms"), class = "factor"), Anti.Anginal.Drug.Therapy.within.2.Weeks = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Age.Group", 
  "Sex", "LOS", "Day.to.Operation", "Admit.Source", "Insurance.Payors", 
  "Current.Recent.Smoker...1.year.", "Hypertension", "Dyslipidemia", 
  "Family.History.of.Premature.CAD", "MI.History", "Heart.Failure.History", 
  "PCI.History", "BMI.Group", "Cerebrovascular.Disease",   "Peripheral.Arterial.Disease", 
  "Chronic.Lung.Disease", "Diabetes.Mellitus", "Diabetes.Therapy", 
  "Heart.Rate", "CAD.Presentation", "STEMI.Non.STEMI.Onset.Date", 
  "STEMI.Non.STEMI.Estimated.Time", "Anginal.Classification.w.in.2.Weeks", 
  "Anti.Anginal.Drug.Therapy.within.2.Weeks"), class = "data.frame",     row.names    = c(NA, 
     -50L))
```

I have performed the string cleaning and missing data treatment as of now. I need help in my next task which is to remove outliers and compute a chi square matrix from this categorical dataset. I am new to data analysis and am quite confused at this point. I would be extremely grateful if I could get help regarding this.